# Using sed to uppercase the first non-numeric character, leave others as is

Tags: sed

I'm trying to convert character strings like "123456**a**" to "123456**A**" or "**t**est" to "**T**est", but leave existing uppercase as is, for example `testHW` becomes `TestHW`.

I have tried many attempts circling around:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]./\u\1/'
```

without luck - any ideas?

Comment: Does that mean you want to replace char at first and last position ?

Comment: I'm automating the processing of remote telemetered data. The standard numbering for this application is 6 digits plus a letter (for a revision code) but humans (as variable as they are) sometimes use uppercase, lowercase, or ignore the standard all together. #cuonglm provided an answer that works in all my test data - capital revision code or at least a polite looking string (initial capital) if they go off standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\1` or general form `\n` where `n` is a digit shall be replaced by the text matched by corresponding back-reference expression, which you define by grouping the text between `\(...\)` with BRE or `(...)` with ERE.

With GNU sed:

```
$ echo 123456a | sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)/\u\1/'
123456A
```

or:

```
$ echo 123456a | sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]])/\u\1/'
123456A
```

You can also use `&` to refer to the text matched instead of back-reference:

```
$ echo 123456a | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\u&/'   
123456A
```

Note that `[:alpha:]` matches both lowercase and uppercase characters, so something like `123456Aa` will be left as-is.

If you want to replace the first lowercase with corresponding uppercase, you must use `[:lower:]`:

```
$ echo 123456Aa | sed 's/[[:lower:]]/\u&/'
123456AA
```